# rescaling ranges

Tags: statistics, gis, interpolation

for example i have two ranges

```
                       (1) 0 to 3
                       (2) 10 to 15
```

in range (1) i have numbers between 0 and 3, where 0 is minimum and 3 is maximum value...(it has also values 1 and 2)...

now i wanted to rescale both ranges (1) and (2) to range 0 to 1. Can you show me how to do it or at least point to helpful sites? thanks a lot!

Comment: "now i wanted to rescale both ranges (1) and (2) to range 0 to 1" - not clear. What output do you want exactly?

Comment: @Riki, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What you're describing is called [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

For the general case, suppose you have a value `c` between `a` and `b`, and you want a value `x` between 0 and 1 which is based on `c`'s relative position between `a` and `b`. The equation for `x` is as follows:

```
x := (c - a) / (b - a)
```

So if you have a value between 10 and 15 (let's say 11), and you want a value between 0 and 1, you punch the values into the equation above:

```
x := (11 - 10) / (15 - 10)
x := 1/5
```

In other words, 11 is one-fifth of the way from 10 to 15.

---

The even more general case (when you have a value `c` between `a` and `b` and you want a value `x` between `y` and `z`), `x` is calculated as follows:

```
x := (c - a) * (z - y) / (b - a) + y
```

In your case, `z = 1` and `y = 0`.